# What are the options for storing thumbnails for all images uploaded with Filepicker.io?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, filepicker.io

I'm using filepicker.io to upload files to s3. As well as storing the original image I'd like to store thumbnails.

The conversion urls are pretty handy. I know [these are cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957492/filepicker-io-convert-and-store-vs-fpurl-conversions) but I think long term I should just be storing the thumbnails.

I tried converting and store in the `filepicker.pickMultiple` success callback but things got a bit messy.

Can I setup the filepicker to do this on upload?

EDIT: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115280/store-files-to-filepicker-io-from-the-command-line) looks like a good solution... still wondering if there are alternatives though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the .convert() call on each of the FPFiles that are returned in the pick() or pickMultiple() call. To help keep the callbacks, etc. manageable, take a look at https://github.com/caolan/async